# SVG export from ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, svg, illustrator

I export my map as an SVG from ArcMap but when I open it on adobe illustrator cc, the map looks so messed up, north arrow not in place and gaps between each letter, text not in the proper size, however when I open the SVG using InkScape it looks just as the MXD.
I have no idea what would cause such problem, I export in 300 DPI and Vectorize layer with Bitmap marker/fill, but I tried of changing the settings but same problem came up.

Comment: A font issue? What do ArcGIS and InkScape report the font as, versus Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: not exactly a font issue the map elements are miss placed and so messy, yes i get a warning once i open the svg on illustrator about " the document uses fonts or characters not available "
on inkScape i get nothing it opens just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of exporting the layout into SVG you can export it directly into illustrator format (*.ai) if you want to use adobe illustrator to edit your layout. Using ai format can open your layout properly in illustrator better than SVG.

Comment: ok i tried that but it doesn't export any fonts, for example the scale is there but no labels exported, the legend the symbols there but also no labels

Comment: is it on the same computer where esri fonts are installed?

Comment: yes same machine

Comment: You have to make sure that fonts used in ArcGIS are also installed in illustrator.